# call webapi from client side that contains additional thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to have ajax call to webapi that:
1) do Calculation method that return List, and this list should be returned to client side
I have the method that does this.

However, now I need to add additional calculations like this:

2) in the same webapi method I need to call method FindBreak, that returns double, but I want to call it in seperate thread and afterwards return to client side.

I never worked with threads / tasks, can you suggest me how to deal with this?

.NET 4.5, webapi

Comment: Can you please clarify how you expect "afterwards return to client side" to work? Or you already figured out that part and just need help with running method on separate thread?

Comment: This is may problem - I do not know how.
I have ajax call currently, it calls webapi and than waits for data. Those data are returned from "1"st part of my question. It seems that I do not know which mechanism could wait for additional data to come.

Comment: Search for something like - "asp.net show progress of long running operation". SignalR as [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26890716/477420) by Max Brodin's answer is an approach... But first consider simply splitting it into 2 calls if possible - would lead to simpler code/less changes and lower requirements on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question details so far:
To start background task you should use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or simular lib like

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => FindBreak());
```

If `afterwards return to client side` means the ability of your server-side code push content to the connected clients you should use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)